# How to re-run debug starting from a line in middle of file?

Tags: debugging, pycharm

In PyCharm, I'm debugging some python code. The first half of the file works great and, unfortunately, takes a little while to run because it is processing a lot of data.

I'm debugging the second half of the file and I'm re-running the entire file every time, which is killing me because of the time it takes to re-process the first half of the code.

I can't make the top half more efficient than it is, so I am trying to find a way to basically **run the top half of the code one time, and then re-run the second half of the file as many times as I need to.**

Is something like this possible? I've read through their documentation and I'm probably missing something because I can't figure out how to do this!

Comment: You can try scientific mode (I'm no sure if it is available in community edition) where you add `# %%` comments to delimiter cells. There is also a [cell-mode](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7858-pycharm-cell-mode) plugin. Then you can run one cell at a time. Pycharm also support jupyter notebooks. Alternatively, you can save the variables generated in the first part with pickle/shelve and load them when running the script a second time to avoid repeating the computation.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the two parts of your code with an if-else statement: E.g.

```py
x = 1
if x == 0:
 #the working parts
else:
 #the other parts
```

When your code is fixed simply remove the if-else loop!